# Folder shares are not visible to all users

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, windows-11

We have two PC's (PC A, and PC B) in the office, both running Windows 10, which offer shared folders to 5 user PC's (PC's 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 - a mix of W10 and W11) on the office LAN. All 5 user PC's can see the shared folders from both PC A and PC B. This has been running fine for a couple of years - until yesterday!!!

Yesterday, PC 5 can no longer see the shares from PC A. All other user PCs can see shares from both PC A and PC B, and PC 5 can see the shares from PC B. There have been no Windows updates to any of the PC's for over a week, and the user of PC 5 assures me he has made no other changes to his PC. PC 5 can ping PC A but if you open a file browser on PC 5 and show the network, PC A does not show. Network discovery is 'On' on all PC's, and I have checked that the other 'Advanced Sharing Settings' on PC 5 match the settings on the other user PC's. The shares on PC A and PC B have priveledges set to 'Everyone' rather than individual user names. Does anyone know what is causing the upset. Many thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0):

I think you could begin the troubleshooting by checking these two configurations:

1. Check if the network is correctly recognized as a domain or private network on the devices, and not a public network. This can be configured on Windows 10 config > Network & Internet > Properties > Toggle Private / Public. I am not sure about Windows 11 but it might be in a similar path.
2. You can reinforce the availability of the network drives using a GPO on each device or reinforcing the GPOs on the domain (if it exists) upon the user login. Below is a guide explaining how to do this:

https://activedirectorypro.com/map-network-drives-with-group-policy/

Remember to use a letter far from the beginning of the alphabet since the first letters will automatically be allocated to local storage and thumb drives, beginning with **C:**